# Why is a static html page loading instead of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed in my main directory for my website and not in /wordpress.  Currently my htaccess file has in it `DirectoryIndex index2.html`.  This points to a static html page that was my landing page before installing wordpress.  Now, when I visit my site after having installed WordPress I am still presented with the same landing page as before.  What do I need to change to make sure that going to my domain will now point to the PHP pages of WordPress instead of my old `html` content?  The site is on a shared Window hosting plan if that makes any difference

Comment: Try posting your .htaccess file.  It's hard to diagnose with this amount of into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you do not have an index.html file in your root WP directory.  index.html files have precedence over the index.php files. That explains why the landing page is loading even when you navigate to a subpage of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment this line or change it to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Something fishier must be going on, because that didn't help, and whatever I change in that file doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: even going to a permalink that SHOULD be a wordpress theme is still showing the same static html.